# Question on operational amplifiers

Tags: voltage, operational-amplifier, circuit-analysis, gain

1.
The following two questions refer to the circuit below.

Consider a non-ideal op amp where the output can saturate.

The open loop gain A = 2 x 10^4 , where vo  =−A*Vs 
The positive supply voltage for the op-amp is +Vs = 15V 
The negative supply voltage for the op-amp is -Vs = -10V

What is the most positive value Vs can take before the amplifier saturates? Express your answer in mV and omit units from your answer.

[image]

2.Question 2
For the circuit above in question 1, what is the most negative value Vs can take before the amplifier saturates? Express your answer in mV and omit units from your answer.

Comment: This is not Chegg. We won't do your homework for you. You need to show a substantial amount of work and ask a specific question.

Answer (score 1):

You know the output cannot exceed -10 to +15V, this is the supply voltages it would saturate against

The gain is the amplification of the difference between the 2 inputs of the opamp, the difference between the + and - inputs, (Inverting and non inverting) e.g. 1mV * gain of 1000 would be 1V,

your signal feeds into the inverting input, so... the output will be an inversion of the input voltage * gain.

I will leave you to solving your actual homework, I believe that should be enough gap filling to reach your own answers.